# Moongose vs. Fetch to get specific JSON data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, fetch

I am confused about the uses of Mongoose and the Fetch API in JavaScript. 
I am currently building a ReactNative Application and have my data in a MongoDB deployed by Heroku. I have some JSON data at '/Jobposts' URL. I would like to search for jobposts in a certain radius. I already have a geoJSON object in my jobposts object. 
The question is should I just be fetching from the URL using fetch? This just gets me ALL the jobs. Or should I use Mongoose query methods like within() and circle()? If so were would I put this code. I currently have Model/Route/Controller set-up now.

```js
    static getJobsWithinRadius(longitude, latitude, radius) {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: header
        };

        return fetch(`${API_URL}/jobposts?longitude=${longitude}&latitude=${latitude}&radius=${radius}`, requestOptions);
    }
```

```js
export const findWithinRadius = (req, res, next) => {

  const longitude = req.params.longitude;
  const latitude = req.params.latitude;
  const radius = req.params.radius;
  const area = { center: [longitude, latitude], radius: radius, unique: true, spherical: true};

   Jobpost.find().where('geometry').within().circle(area).lean().exec((err, jobposts) => res.json(
     jobposts.map(jobpost => ({
       ...jobpost,
     }))
   ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using it as the way it is is correct mate ...  Model/Route/Controller is the way to go when you develop a node REST service

Comment: So right now I am calling my findWithinRadius() in my routes after a get request goes to '{API_URL}/jobopsts', but my findWithinRadius() is never used. It just returns all the jobposts as if I didn't make a route.